# Download Unsuccessfull error in android device

Tags: php, http-headers, download

I am trying to download image using php and htaccess but its not working in default android problem.

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\""); 
readfile(base_url($go));
```

also tried

```
header('Content-Type: IMAGE MIME TYPE');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\""); 
readfile(base_url($go));
```

I have tried this but not working also tried htaccess code

AddType image/jpg jpg

also tried force download using htaccess.
Is something wrong in my code or something wrong in android default browser ?
its working well with Pc browsers.

Comment: Little sense in _guessing_ what _might_ be going on. Check these first: what do the http servers log files say? Especially the code in the access log file? If that is fine (return code 200) then use a network sniffer to see what is actually transferred.

Comment: i dont have ssh access so how can i check that ?

Comment: In that case you probably have no access to the log files. This situation is always like searching for something in the dark... wenn then, on to step two: use a network sniffer to see what is really contained in the payload.